# List<T> & where T :

Tags: c#, list

I have simple code witch works ok:

```
public class Example
{

    private List<SomeClass> _list = new List<SomeClass>();

    public void Add(SomeClass _b) {
        _list.Add(_b);
    }

}
```

it possible to add SomeClass to _list something like this? (without specifying argument)?

```
public void Add<T>() where T : SomeClass
{

}
```

Comment: No - what are you adding? There's no instance to add there.

Comment: If there is no argument, what do you intend to add?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Based on the answer you accepted I am really curious about WHY you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `SomeClass` has a default constructor, you can:

```
public void Add<T>() where T : SomeClass, new()
{
    _list.Add(new T());
}
```

If `SomeClass` does not have a default constructor then you won't be able to write `new T()` and you will need to find another way of getting a `T` object.

Answer (score 4):

You may use generics:

```
public class Example<T>
{
 private List<T> = _list = new List<T>();
 public void Add(T element)
 {
   _list.Add(element);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What would you be adding? I don't see any point to that. The external consumer of `Example` would not be able to add anything.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do

```
public void Add<T>(T _b) where T : SomeClass
{

}
```

But it is pretty pointless and means the same thing as you existing code.